# Можно ли ограничить доступ в приложение

Tags: android

Можно ли отказать в доступе в приложение если нет интернета(чтобы показывать рекламу)? Многие пользователи пользуются приложением отключив интерент, чтобы не видеть рекламу, в результате доходы разработчика на нуле

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос в вашем же вопросе.

Comment: Можно проверять внутри приложения доступность какого-либо ресурса в сети интернет и если ресурс недоступен, приложение закрывать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В onCreate проверяйте доступность интернета,через  connectivity manager, потом, вызывайте например, диалог ,который утверждает ,что подключения к интернету нет и заказывайте приложение методом finish().

```
public boolean isOnline() {

    ConnectivityManager cm =

        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();

}
```

Не забывайте о

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```